# JPA persist two joined tables, how many persitence contexts?

Tags: jpa

I want to persist to two tables using JPA.  Should I use one persistence context service or a service for each entity I want to persist?

Answer (score 0):

As your tables are joined then a single persistence context would be needed.

If the tables are related as in your case, for example the entities that map to them are related with `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToMany`, or they are related in the sense that your application will process the tables together in some way, then using one persistence context would be the way to go.

If they are not conceptually linked in this way then they can be separated into different persistence contexts as defined in the persistence-unit tag of the persistence.xml file.